# Why is this (extended) wildcard matching a filename that I'm trying to exclude?

Tags: bash, wildcards

Why is **'myscript.txt'** displayed when I run the command

```
$ ls !(my)*.txt
myscript.txt
hey.txt
```

and on the same note, how is bash interpreting `$ ls !(my)*.txt` and `$ ls !(my*).txt`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`!(my)*.txt` matches on `myscript.txt` because

- `!(my)` matches on the empty string
- `*` matches on `myscript`
- `.txt` matches on `.txt`

(or `!(my)` matches on `myscript` and `*` on the empty string, or `!(my)` matches on `m` and `*` on `yscript`...).

You want `!(my*).txt` if you want to match on file names that end in `.txt` and don't start with `my`.

Note that `!(*)` is a ksh-specific operator. It's now also supported by `bash` but only when the `extglob` option is on and by `zsh`, but only when the `kshglob` option is on.

`zsh` also has its own `extendedglob`s which come with its `^` negation operator and `~` *except* / *and-not* operator:

```
set -o extendedglob
ls -ld -- (^my*).txt
ls -ld -- *.txt~my*
```

The *except* / *and-not* operator can be implemented in `ksh93` with:

```
ls -ld -- @(*.txt&!(my*))
```

or with `bash -O extglob` and older version of ksh with

```
ls -ld -- !(!(*.txt)|my*)
```

Note though that they differ from `zsh`'s `~` operator in that the latter applies as a final filter on whole glob pattern, while the `!(...)`, `@(...)` can only operate on a single path component of the glob (for example `*/b*~f*r` excludes `foo/bar` from the expansion of `*/b*`)

Comment: I'm still confused on why !(my) matches on empty string, because ! matches only when none of the pattern matches, which shouldn't expand myscript.txt, therefore not including it in the result :/

Comment: Does it mean that even though 'my' matches with 'my', bash is comparing 'my' with just 'm' and rest is matched with *.txt?

Comment: @sh.3.ll `!(my)` matches _any_ string except `my`, including the empty string. `*` matches any string _including_ `my` (and the empty string). This means that `!(my)*.txt` matches `myfile.txt`. I don't know how this can be said more clearly. What part of the filename that `!(my)` matches and what part `*` matches is less important.